# How to hide legends and axis in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is their any possibility to hide all rounded items from this picture.

[image]

I have used the following code,

```
public void setDataList(List<HorizontalBarChartData> dataList, Resources resources) {

    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> values = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
    BarDataSet set1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        categories.add(dataList.get(i).getName());
        values.add(new BarEntry(dataList.get(i).getValue(), i));
    }

    /*set1 = new BarDataSet(values, "Income, Expense, Disposable Income");*/
    set1 = new BarDataSet(values, "Category 1, Category 2, Category 3");
    set1.setBarSpacePercent(35f);
    set1.setColors(new int[]{resources.getColor(R.color.cyan_blue), resources.getColor(R.color.vermilion_tint), resources.getColor(R.color.sea_green)});
    dataSets.add(set1);

    BarData data = new BarData(categories, dataSets);
    data.setValueTextSize(10f);

    horizontalBarChart.setData(data);
}
```

**Update**

How to hide rounded part from this image?

[image]

Comment: Where is your `MPAndroidChart` codes ?

Comment: Hey @Gunaseelan, Could you check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975333/mpandroidchart-horizontalbarchart-customize-label?noredirect=1#comment65304760_38975333

Comment: How did you write above the bars ? Can anyone tell this ?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Yes, is possible, just using following code:

```
mChart.setDescription("");    // Hide the description
mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);

mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);   // Hide the legend
```

Comment: My MPAndroidChart version is v2.0.7

Comment: Is possible to hide `Category 1, Category 2, Category 3` legend bro.

Comment: In my project, i use mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false) to hide it. But my x axis is left, not right.

Comment: Yes, bro, you can use mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false) to hide legend, but be careful: you need to set data for the chart before calling this method. It means you should call after mChart.setData().

Comment: Can we hide the background box bro.

Comment: In v3.0.3 to hide the description you need to do this: `Description description = new Description(); description.setText(""); mChart.setDescription(description);`

Comment: Just fyi: the description can now be hidden in Kotlin (and also Java) bij using:
`mChart.description.isEnabled = false` or `mChart.description.setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 7):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29031527/2820534)

`mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);` will hide the entire X-Axis(as required for this question).

For positioning the X-Axis, following code works.

```
    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Position can be set to

- BOTTOM
- BOTH_SIDED
- BOTTOM_INSIDE
- TOP
- TOP_INSIDE

This helps if you are trying to hide only the particular side axis instead of hiding the entire axis.

Answer (score 7):

It appears `mChart.setDescription()` no longer accepts a String.

The method now accepts an instance of the Description Class like this:
`mChart.setDescription(Description description)`

So to modify or delete the Chart Description you may do it like below

```java
Description description = new Description();
description.setText("");
mChart.setDescription(description);
```

Answer (score 5):

Following code work for all chart

`Legend l = mchart.getLegend();
 l.setEnabled(false);`.

Answer (score 4):

To hide description, use this

```
mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for PieChart. Try to get same method for your Chart.

```
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
l.setPosition(LegendPosition.NONE);
```

Comment: @Gunaseelan No method available as horizontalBarChart.getLegend()??

Comment: No, `Legend.LegendPosition.NONE` is not available.

Comment: LegendPosition.NONE has been removed. use legend.setEnabled(false) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart=(LineChart) findViewById(R.id.Chart);
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false); // for hiding square on below graph
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution for `MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0`

```
chart.description.isEnabled = false // hide the description
chart.legend.isEnabled = false // hide the legend 

chart.xAxis.setDrawLabels(false) // hide bottom label
chart.axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false) // hide left label
chart.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false) // hide right label
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, that the bottom xAxis Labels are cutted off when I used `mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false)`

Now I use  `chart.getLegend().setForm(Legend.LegendForm.NONE);` instead and the labels are not cutted of anymore